# How to show hidden sysctl tunable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, systemd, sysctl

I'm on a Yocto Linux distribution and I need to set the sysctl tunable `kernel.panic_on_rcu_stall` to 1. The problem is when I list the elements inside `/proc/sys/kernel` I have no `panic_on_rcu_stall` and if I try to set the option anyway I get the folowing error:

```
# sysctl -w kernel.panic_on_rcu_stall=1
sysctl: error: 'kernel.panic_on_rcu_stall' is an unknown key
```

I know that the key exist, we can see it on the [Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html), but it also specify that

> Currently, these files might (**depending on your configuration**) show up in /proc/sys/kernel:

And this is all about, what the documentation means by *your configuration* and how to change it.

I'm using the `4.4.38+linaro` Linux kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should configure and build a new kernel. For "your configuration" you should read "the configuration of kernel you used to build it".

Comment: In kernel 4.4. there is no `panic_on_rcu_stall` option. The option appears only in 4.8: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/C/ident/sysctl_panic_on_rcu_stall.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will update the kernel and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, Tsyvarev was right, after applying [this patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=088e9d253d3a4ab7e058dd84bb532c32dadf1882) to my kernel recipe in my Yocto project, the option `kernel.panic_on_rcu_stall` appeared in `/proc/sys/kernel`.